# Why are there unnecessary white spaces in the following point additions?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to understand TikZ's point addition with several combinatorial cases as follows. I noticed there are unnecessary white spaces. What causes this phenomenon?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lightgray,thin,dashed] (-1,-1)  grid  (4,4);
    \fill[thick,blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick,red,->] 
        (0,0)+(10,10)+(9,9)+(0,2) 
            -- (-1,-1)+(1,0)++(2,1) 
            -- (3,2)+(-2,1) 
            -- ++(-1,1)+(1,-3) 
            -- ++(1,-2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The extraneous use of `+(10,10)`, while it does not end up in the drawn line, being superseded by `+(0,2)`, actually extends the tikz page to (10,10), whereas the grid only extends to (4,4).

Commenting out the `+(10,10)+(9,9)` remedies the overextended page.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lightgray,thin,dashed] (-1,-1)  grid  (4,4);
    \fill[thick,blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick,red,->] 
        (0,0)%+(10,10)+(9,9)
       +(0,2) 
            -- (-1,-1)+(1,0)++(2,1) 
            -- (3,2)+(-2,1) 
            -- ++(-1,1)+(1,-3) 
            -- ++(1,-2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]